# Case after разучиться

Tags: падежи, глаголы

Most verbs derived from **учиться** answer the question "**чему**?". However, my textbook just cites "**делать что**?" as the question to be answered by **разучиться**.

Can разучиться be followed by a noun rather than a verb, and if so does the noun take the dative case like учиться, научиться and обучаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разучиться **only** takes an *infinitive* after it: **разучиться** (что делать?) **стрелять**. A similar verb **отучить(ся)** (= to quit some habit or make somebody quit it) can take either an *infinitive*  (**отучить** кого-либо **поступать** так-то) or a *noun* with the *preposition* **от** (**отучить/ся/ от привычки**).

Comment: Maybe отучиться is the solution when I want to refer to a noun I lost practice of?

Comment: _Отучить(ся)_ is about an _intentional_ action, so it usually can't replace the verb _разучиться_ which is typically about losing skill due to lack of practice, etc.

Answer (score 3):

No, it can't be followed by a noun.

You can say "учиться стрелять" or "учиться стрельбе", both are OK. But only "разучиться стрелять". You can't say "разучиться стрельбе", it is wrong. If you use "разучиться" in more complicated cases, you would have to re-phrase, if there's no one-to-one correspondence between a noun and a verb. For example, you can't simply invert "учиться военному делу настоящим образом", would have to say something like "разучиться воевать".